# Will my game fit on the available HDD space?

Tags: ps4, hard-drive

I have FFX/X-2 remastered and am trying to install it on PS4. Despite uninstalling some of the TV addons like Netflix & Hulu, there isn't enough space for installation.

How do I estimate the amount of disk space necessary and how much is needed to uninstall?

Comment: This question/answer does not seem particularly helpful.  The "answer" seems to essentially be "look it up", which is the obvious approach.

Comment: Shouldn't the game tell you how much space it will take up when you go to install it?  I know Xbox One does that.  Also why use the [tag:xbox-one] when you're clearly asking about [tag:ps4]?

Comment: @BlueBarren My actual question was for a game on PS4. Since I found info on both system, I added Xbox One as well for a tag. Also, I didn't see any info on how much space it would take installed - just 'insufficient space on disk' message - will check if I missed something.

Comment: @Alok If your asking about PS4 why did you use the Xbox One tag?

Comment: @Ramhound Thought people could have same issue on Xbox One - but both you and BlueBarren think it shouldn't have that tag, so I'll remove it :)

Comment: [31.8 GB](https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/games/final-fantasy-x-x-2-hd-remaster/cid=UP0082-CUSA01227_00-FFX0FFX20USA0PS4)

Comment: FINAL FANTASY X/X-2 HD Remaster doesn't even exist on Xbox One

Comment: @Ramhound that's quite odd. your US link says 31.8 GB but the Australian link i posted shows 32.1 GB

Comment: So take the higher and it will install no matter what.  The US store and Australian store might include separate data

Comment: Checked again and PS4 does mention how much additional space needs to be freed up. Sorry, can't delete it as there is already an upvoted answer :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BlueBarren](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/314770/will-my-game-fit-on-the-available-hdd-space#comment447537_314770) is correct. i am fairly certain that every PS4 game has the Required HDD space on the back of the cover, for instance *Final Fantasy XII: The Zodiac Age* says it needs about around 40-something GB which is way to much for a save file, which it too is also listed in the back.

i have noticed all physical PS4 games i have brought are also available digitally as such disk space should also be documented in the Playstation Store, both on the PS4 and the Browser Version. However since this is a digital version and thus doesn't have a disk to play off from the size would be greater, but if you go by this size as an estimate you will be certain you have enough space if you play a physical version

[for Final Fantasy X/X-2 on PS4](https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-au/games/final-fantasy-x-x-2-hd-remaster/cid=EP0082-CUSA01244_00-FFX0FFX200EU0PS4) it's digital version required 32.1 GB for the game and 11 MB for saves minimum. the latter will always be the same regardless of what version you play

[image: Final Fantasy X/X-2 on Playstation Store]

---

it is also quite possible that the same can be done for XBOne games however i don't have an XBOne to double check the store, however i do recall on the XB360 the store on it would list Disk Sizes for games so assuming the same for the XBOne you can too use this as an estimate for a physical games

Comment: It may be worth noting that the OP was attempting to delete TV apps in an effort to save space, but the TV apps are tiny (100-300mb) whereas games are much larger space hogs.

Answer (score 1):

There are sites that have a list of almost all game titles with their installed sizes, which makes it far easier to figure out what to uninstall to fit in a new game on an almost-full disk.

PS4: https://www.finder.com/complete-list-playstation-4-install-sizes-460-titles

XBox One: https://www.finder.com/xbox-one-install-sizes